# Listing Sub-Pages & Sub-Sub-Pages

Tags: navigation, sub-menu, wp-list-pages

So I don't really know why I am having so much trouble with this, it seems like functionality in wordpress that should be a bit easier to working with.

Anyhow **I need to generate a menu system for a sidebar that looks like this (for a top level page):**

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Sub-Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Sub-Page</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Sub-Sub-Page</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub-Sub-Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Sub-Page</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Sub-Sub-Page</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub-Sub-Page</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub-Sub-Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Sub-Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

On top if this, **I need to show the same menu, no matter how deep in the sub pages the user is at**.

For example, if I was on a sub-sub-page, then I still wish to show the same menu.

In other words, even if I was at a 3rd level page, it would still show 3rd and 2nd level pages - exactly the same as the above menu.

---

Thanks for the help in this one!

Comment: What is the code that creates the menu?

Comment: I don't really have code that 'creates' the menu besides what I have answered with :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out to be a bit easier than I thought:

```
                <?php

                if ($post->post_parent) {
                    $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
                    $root=count($ancestors)-1;
                    $parent = $ancestors[$root];
                } else {
                    $parent = $post->ID;
                }

                ?>

                <?php $args = array(
                    'depth'        => 0,
                    'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
                    'child_of'     => $parent,
                    'title_li'     => __(''),
                    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title'
                ); ?>


                <ul>

                  <?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?> 

                </ul>
```